# Is it possible to run users' jobs in chroot environment using Slurm

Tags: permissions, chroot, slurm

I'm using `Slurm`. I want users only to access their own `/home/` directory (or directory that they executed their job), ubuntu packages that is installed by the `sudo` user, and binary files user `/bin`, such as: `ls`, `cat`, `rm` etc.

I do not want each user to have any `read/write` access to the other users' files and important files such as `/etc/passwd`.

I observe that when any `slurm-job` runs under a new user, it can `read` all files under the root (`/`) directory such as `/etc/passwd`.

---

From the starting point of the answer to [Is it possible to force SLURM to have access to only job's running folder and not alter any other file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540590/is-it-possible-to-force-slurm-to-have-access-to-only-jobs-running-folder-and-no), it has been recommended to use `chroot`:

> If you want to make sure your job has no way to write outside of a
>   specific directory, you can use the `chroot` command in your job
>   submission script, but that seems a bit odd and less easy to manage
>   than UNIX permissions.

---

> The `chroot()` system call changes the process’s root directory to the
>   directory specified by pathname

Is it possible to run users' jobs in the chroot environment (`chroot()-jailed`) using `Slurm`?

---

*As an alternative solution, I have controlled the files access is through UNIX permissions, where a job can only write where the submitting user has permission to write, please see:*
[slurm: How to submit a job under another user and prevent to read other users' files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58860185/2402577)